# Gnome 3 move window to 2nd monitor?

Tags: linux, gnome, linux-mint

I am running Mint Linux 12 with Gnome 3. My setup has 2 screen. I am wondering if there is a program to move the windows to a 2nd monitor? Something like display fusion for Linux that makes a button on the window title bar to move the window to the left display or the to the right display.

If not someway to do this via keyboard commands would work as well.

Comment: Related Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/297819/move-window-to-another-monitor-in-ubuntu-using-keyboard

Comment: Super+Shift+Left/Right/Up/Down Arrow
<br>
Source: https://superuser.com/questions/684432/hotkey-to-move-window-to-other-monitor

Answer (score 0):

The very last item on the [GnomeShell Cheatsheet](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet)
is:

> System (Windows) key+Shift+Right/Left arrow: move window to right/left
> monitor

You may also want to check out the full cheatsheet (it will come in very handy).