# Hotkey to Move Window to Other Monitor

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm running Linux Mint with Cinnamon using two monitors.  Is there a hotkey combo that moves the window from the current monitor to the other?

I can hold Windows Key + left/right/up arrow to move/ maximize, however it doesn't allow you to move the window to the other screen.

Anyone know of one that exists?

Comment: @Martin Jiřička solution works. He deserves to have his answer as accepted.

Comment: @AlbertEngelB The answer of Martin Jiřička is the answer to your question. Please accept.

Comment: @Socrates I no longer have a Mint install that I can verify that it works or not.  I know that on the version I was running at the time it didn't do what I was wanting, so I do not feel comfortable accepting it as an answer.

Comment: @AlbertEngelB I have Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa with Cinnamon and the answer with currently 20 upvotes works perfectly. You can tick that as an answer to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 64):

On my Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon edition are predefined shortcuts <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right/Up/Down Arrow</kbd>. They move active window to screen on left, right, above, below (depending on the arrow key). It works even on fullscreen windows.

Comment: Ctrl + Super / Windows key will move it around on the currently active monitor, however it doesn't actually move it to the other display (I'm on Linux Mint 17 Qiana).

Comment: @AlbertEngelB I have Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa with Cinnamon. If I take any window, i.e. Google Chrome, and click on it for the focus, and then hold **Super** and **Shift**, I can then move the window between the three of my monitors by also holding either **Left Arrow** or **Right Arrow**. The window is then moved to the other monitor.

Comment: This is not quite what's being asked. Chrome OS has a shortcut which means exactly "Move window to other monitor". It's great for the common case of laptop + external monitor because it simply toggles the window back and forth, without any thought required about left vs right. It's also helpful if you are trying to use the same key combo between Chrome OS and Linux.

Answer (score 24):

With Gnome 3, you can use
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.

[image: enter keyboard shortcuts]

It might work under Cinnamon, since it is based on Gnome 3.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work (at least on Linux Mint 17).

Comment: Option missing in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

It works for Ubuntu 20.04 too!

Just use `Super`+`Shift` + `left/right arrow`.

`Super` is the key with Windows/Apple logo usually.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Mint Cinnamon Edition, the shortcuts can be found in the "Windows / Inter-monitor" category:

[image: screenshot of keyboard shortcuts dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrow.

It should move the active window to the desired screen.

Comment: This changes what workspace the window is in, I'm trying to stay in the same workspace on the separate monitor.

Answer (score 0):

In Nobara Linux (GNOME 42.3.1), these short cuts were not set for me, but I was able to easily set them in Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shortcuts -> Navigation.

Shift-Super-Left and Shift-Super-Right now work for me to move windows between monitors.