# How to move all windows to a different monitor with Gnome / wayland?

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, gnome, wayland

It's all in the title. My computer has an 8 inches **screen**. I often plug/unplugged it to a bigger 22 inches **monitor**. I also usually have many (dozens) windows of various things opened in  5 workspaces. The windows does not automatically jump to the bigger **screen** nor I know about a keybinding or another way (terminal command would be fine) to make them move all at once **to the bigger screen** (at least for the current workspace).

Right now I have to move them one at a time :/.

(I'm on debian sid with gnome ... I just looked in preferences and next to "gnome version" it says "not available"...  but it was 41.2 IIRC last time I checked)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is discussed in the post
[How to move all windows to another workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470324/how-to-move-all-windows-to-another-workspace),
with several answers.

- [Script for Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/758339/963426)
  that uses xdotool (too long to quote here)
- For
  [Non-Compiz based desktop environments (XFCE, LXDE, GNOME, KDE...)](https://askubuntu.com/a/589930/963426)
  use these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
  while read i; do wmctrl -i -t 2 -r "$i"  ; done  < <(wmctrl -l | awk -v var=$(xdotool get_desktop) '{if ($2 == var) print $0;}' | cut -d' '  -f1)
  ```

For more information, see the linked post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to move windows to different workspaces, but to a different monitor.

Comment: Monitors are distinguished by screen coordinates, so xdotool & wmctrl can move also between monitors. See [example1](https://superuser.com/questions/297819/move-window-to-another-monitor-in-ubuntu-using-keyboard), [example2](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=290312), [example3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170491/how-to-move-active-window-to-another-display-in-xfce).